# Passing internal parameter to controller functions with Redirect

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-3

in controller i have `getEdit` function and i want to pass parameter from this controller functions with `Redirect::route`.

for example

this functions get parameter normally:

```
public function getEdit( $entryExitid )
{

}
```

and with this function i want to pass parameter for that

```
public function postUpdate()
{
        return Redirect::route('entryAndExit.edit','10')
            ->withErrors( Lang::get('message.exitTimeBiggerThanEntryTime') )
            ->withInput();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 return Redirect::route('entryAndExit.edit',array('entryExitid' => $id))
```